# Link List Problem,

Tags: c++, hyperlink, linked-list

OK i have a problem with a Link List program i'm trying to Do,

the link List is working fine.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct record
{
    string word;
    struct record * link;
};
typedef struct record node;


node * insert_Node( node * head, node * previous,  string key );
node * search( node *head, string key, int *found);
void displayList(node *head);
node * delete_node( node *head, node * previous, string key);



int main()
{

    node * previous,  * head = NULL;
    int found = 0;
    string node1Data,newNodeData, nextData,lastData;


    //set up first node
    cout <<"Depature"<<endl;
    cin >>node1Data;
    previous = search( head, node1Data, &found);
    cout <<"Previous" <<previous<<endl;
    head = insert_Node(head, previous, node1Data);
    cout <<"Depature inserted"<<endl;

    //insert node between first node and head
    cout <<"Destination"<<endl;
    cin >>newNodeData;
    previous = search( head, newNodeData, &found);
    cout <<"Previous" <<previous<<endl;
    head = insert_Node(head, previous, newNodeData);
    cout <<"Destinationinserted"<<endl;

        //insert node between second node and head
    cout <<"Cost"<<endl;
    cin >>newNodeData;
    previous = search( head, newNodeData, &found);
    cout <<"Previous" <<previous<<endl;
    head = insert_Node(head, previous, newNodeData);
    cout <<"Cost inserted"<<endl;
    cout <<"Number of Seats Required"<<endl;

    //place node between new node and first node
    cin >>nextData;
    previous = search( head, nextData, &found);
    cout <<"Previous" <<previous<<endl;
    head = insert_Node(head, previous, nextData);
    cout <<"Number of Seats Required inserted"<<endl;

        //insert node between first node and head
    cout <<"Name"<<endl;
    cin >>newNodeData;
    previous = search( head, newNodeData, &found);
        cout <<"Previous" <<previous<<endl;
    head = insert_Node(head, previous, newNodeData);
    cout <<"Name inserted"<<endl;

        //insert node between  node and head
    cout <<"Address "<<endl;
    cin >>newNodeData;
    previous = search( head, newNodeData, &found);
    cout <<"Previous" <<previous<<endl;
    head = insert_Node(head, previous, newNodeData);
    cout <<"Address inserted"<<endl;

    //place node as very last node
    cin >>lastData;
    previous = search( head, lastData, &found);
    cout <<"Previous" <<previous<<endl;
    head = insert_Node(head, previous, lastData);
    cout <<"C"<<endl;

    displayList(head);


    char Ans = 'y';
    //Delete nodes
    do


    {
        cout <<"Enter Keyword to be delete"<<endl;
        cin >>nextData;
        previous = search( head, nextData, &found);
        if (found == 1)
            head = delete_node( head, previous,nextData);
        displayList(head);
        cout <<"Do you want to Delete more   y /n "<<endl;
        cin >> Ans;
    }


        while( Ans =='y');









        int choice, i=0, counter=0;
    int fclass[10];
        int coach[10];
    printf("Welcome to the booking program");
    printf("\n-----------------");
    do{
        printf("\n Please pick one of the following option:");
        printf("\n 1) Reserve a first class seat on Flight 101.");
        printf("\n 2) Reserve a coach seat on Flight 101.");
        printf("\n 3) Quit ");
        printf("\n ---------------------------------------------------------------------");
        printf("\nYour choice?");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                i++;

                if (i <10){
                    printf("Here is your seat: %d " , fclass[i]);
                }
                else if (i = 10)
                {

                    printf("Sorry there is no more seats on First Class. Please wait for the next flight");
                }
                break;
                    case 2:
                        if (i <10){
                            printf("Here is your Seat Coach: %d " , coach[i]);

                        }
                        else if ( i = 10)
                        {

                            printf("Sorry their is no more Seats on Coach. Please wait for the next flight");
                        }
                        break;

            case 3:
                printf("Thank you and goodbye\n");
                //exit(0);
        }
    } while (choice != 3);
}














/*******************************************************
search function to return previous position of node
******************************************************/
node * search( node *head, string key, int *found)
{

node * previous, * current;
current = head; previous = current;

*found = 0;//not found

//if (current->word  < key) move through links until the next link
//matches  or current_word  > key

while( current !=NULL)
{
    //compare exactly
    if  (key ==current->word  )
    {
        *found = 1;
        break;
    }
    //if key is less than word
    else if (  key < current->word  )
        break;

    else

    {
        //previous stays one link behind current
        previous = current;
        current = previous -> link;
    }
}


    return previous;
}

/********************************************************
 display function as used with createList
 ******************************************************/

void displayList(node *head)
{
    node * current;

//current now contains the address held of the  1st node similar //to head
    current = head;

    cout << "\n\n";

    if( current ==NULL)
        cout << "Empty List\n\n";

    else
    {
         /*Keep going displaying the contents of the list and
          set current to the address of the next node.
          When set to null, there are no more nodes
         */

        while(current !=NULL)
        {
                    cout << current->word<<endl;
                    current = current ->link;
        }
      }
 }








/************************************************************
 insert node used to position node
 (i) empty list    head = NULL
 (ii) to position node before the first node key < head->word
 (iii) every other position including the end of the list

 This is done using the following steps
 (a) Pass in all the details to create the node either details or a whole record
 (b) Pass the details over to fill the node
 (C) Use the if statement to add the node to the list
 **********************************************************/

node * insert_Node( node * head, node * previous,  string key )
{

node * new_node, * temp;

new_node = new node;  //create the node

new_node ->word = key;
new_node -> link = NULL;



if (head == NULL ||  key < head->word  )  //empty list
{
        //give address of head to temp
        temp = head;

        //head now points to the new_node
            head = new_node;

         //new_node now points to what head was pointing at
            new_node -> link = temp;

}

else
 {
    //pass address held in link to temp
    temp = previous-> link;

         //put address of new node to link of previous
         previous -> link = new_node;

         //pass address of temp to link of new node
         new_node -> link = temp;

}


return head;

}


node * delete_node( node *head, node * previous, string key)
{
    /* this function will delete a node  but will not return its
             contents */
    node * temp;

    if(key == head->word) //delete node at head of list
    {
        temp = head;

                  //point head at the next node
        head = head -> link;
    }
    else

{
        //holds the address of the node after the one
        // to be deleted
        temp = previous-> link;

                   /*assign the previous to the address of the
                     present node to be deleted which holds
                     the address of the next node */

        previous-> link = previous-> link-> link;
        }


    delete   temp;
    return head;
}//end delete
```

The problem i have is when i Enter in the Number 2 in the Node(Seats) i like to get a Counter Taken 2 off of 50, some thing like what i have here

```
enter code here

    int choice, i=0, counter=0;
int fclass[10];
    int coach[10];
printf("Welcome to the booking program");
printf("\n-----------------");
do{
    printf("\n Please pick one of the following option:");
    printf("\n 1) Reserve a first class seat on Flight 101.");
    printf("\n 2) Reserve a coach seat on Flight 101.");
    printf("\n 3) Quit ");
    printf("\n ---------------------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\nYour choice?");
    scanf("%d",&choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
            i++;

            if (i <10){
                printf("Here is your seat: %d " , fclass[i]);
            }
            else if (i = 10)
            {

                printf("Sorry there is no more seats on First Class. Please wait for the next flight");
            }
            break;
                case 2:
                    if (i <10){
                        printf("Here is your Seat Coach: %d " , coach[i]);

                    }
                    else if ( i = 10)
                    {

                        printf("Sorry their is no more Seats on Coach. Please wait for the next flight");
                    }
                    break;

        case 3:
            printf("Thank you and goodbye\n");
            //exit(0);
    }
} while (choice != 3);
```

How can i get what the User enters into number of Seats into this function

Comment: Side note: your conditional statements in your second code block need double equal signs (==).

Comment: Is this linked list supposed to be sorted by `word`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking for, but if I understand your question, you're trying to get the value of 2 into delete_node().

In your sample code, you read user input into an integer. Since delete_node() takes a string as its search argument, you'll just need to convert it first.

Either way, be sure to fix your `else if()` statements. You want `(i == 10)` and not `(i = 10)` since you're looking for equality, not assignment.